# Checking the clipboard contents

Tags: java, clipboard

so I was adding a feature into my game where you can copy your clipboard into the chat box so I have this code

```
public static String getClipboardContents() {
    String result = "";
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
    boolean hasTransferableText = (contents != null)
            && contents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    if (hasTransferableText) {
        try {
            result = (String) contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
        } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return result;

}
```

}

```
if ((keyevent.isControlDown() && keyevent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_V)) {
        client.inputString += client.getClipboardContents();
        client.inputTaken = true;
    }
```

so then I thought why not make it so when you clipboard is empty the button shows up gray and when it is not it shows up another image so I made this void where it draws my buttons

```
private void drawChatTools() {

//Draws All tools buttons to start with 
Pastebtn.drawAdvancedSprite(440,106);
Clearbtn.drawAdvancedSprite(458,107);
Weelbtn.drawAdvancedSprite(476,106);
```

}

but I was wondering how would I make it so the java code can see if the clipboard is empty or not?

Answer (score 1):

> so then I thought why not make it so when you clipboard is empty the
>   button shows up gray

This usually ends up screwing up other clipboard functionality.  You should not perform any invasive clipboard monitoring just for the purposes of lighting a button or menu.  It's ok to see what formats are available, but if you actually examine the data, then you're in effect, causing a paste. Which is going to have all sorts of unintended consequences, such as triggering the Delayed Rendering mechanism, and possibly causing network traffic (in the case of remote desktop or synchronized desktop/clipboard apps).

Clipboard Abuse is the path to the dark side. Clipboard Abuse leads to anger. Anger leads to hate. Hate leads to suffering.